# CSS Selector nth-child() for different colors

Tags: html, css

I have a parent DIV with 5 Child DIVs, each Child DIV has the same class and that appears to be the problem. I am trying to put a different background color for each child DIV? But something seems to be going wrong with the CSS. Thoughts?

**CSS**

```
   .rsThumbsContainer:nth-child(2){
        background: rgb(184,84,84);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="rsThumbsContainer">
 <div class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
    <div class="rsTmb">Frugobee video</div>
 </div>
 <div class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
   <div class="rsTmb">Post a job</div>
 </div>
 <div class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
  <div class="rsTmb">Get a quote</div>
 </div>
 <div class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
  <div class="rsTmb">Make a hire</div>
 </div>
 <div class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
  <div class="rsTmb">Pay with ease</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

I know it can be done using ID's and JQuery.

Comment: Why you made it so much complicated ? :o

Comment: I can't even read this CSS.

Comment: What is going wrong? Is there no background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See example.
You need set :nth-child on

```
<div class="rsNavItem rsThumb">
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7n5xN/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `nth-child` to the child selector, not the parent:

```
.rsNavItem:nth-child(2) { 
  background: rgb(184,84,84); 
}
```

Comment: Also if you want to repeat it for each even children, you need to replace "2" with "2n", or for the odd childrens "2n+1"